# SSIS Data Transformation - Rows to Columns

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have a situation in m current ssis project. I have a huge excel with customer data. The 2 columns have identifiers for the customer data. Something like below. Rest of columns have actual data.

```
COLUMN A | COLUMN B
--------------------
NAME     | XYZ
ADDRESS1 | 1 STREET
ADDRESS2 | APT A    
ZIP      | 12345
```

The challenge is to Read the values into a variable or to a column. This is required for validations to be performed. After the transformation, I need data in below format.

```
NAME | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ZIP
--------------------------------------
XYZ  | 1 STREET | APT A    | 12345
```

I may not be able to use Pivot transformation because this data is read using script component for a dynamic columns. Can anyone please provide me a solution for this ?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out of the box is going to help you. The challenge you face is that your key-value data has an implicit grouping. That is, every time you see the `Name` key, the next N rows are associated back to the opening row.

Since you're already reading data in from a Script task, do what makes sense and instead of outputting in a KVP, redefine your output buffer to be Name, Address1, Address2, Zip with appropriate lengths. Then, in your script task, don't actually call the `AddRow()` method until you've reached the end of the file or you've encountered a Name row.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Script component. The code is given below. Assumption: There are no missing field values. This code will get you started. After that you would need to tweak it according to your special requirements.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
string name = string.Empty;
string address1 = string.Empty;
string address2 = string.Empty;
string zip = string.Empty;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
}
public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
 }
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.Key.ToUpper().Equals("NAME"))
    {
        name = Row.Value;
    }
    else if (Row.Key.ToUpper().Equals("ADDRESS1"))
    {
        address1 = Row.Value;
    }
    else if (Row.Key.ToUpper().Equals("ADDRESS2"))
    {
        address2 = Row.Value;
    }
    else if (Row.Key.ToUpper().Equals("ZIP"))
    {
        zip = Row.Value;

        OutputRowBuffer.AddRow();
        OutputRowBuffer.Name = name;
        OutputRowBuffer.Address1 = address1;
        OutputRowBuffer.Address2 = address2;
        OutputRowBuffer.Zip = zip;           
    }
}
```

}